# javascript checkbox onchange with dynamic id and name

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, onchange

I have a table which dynamically inserts rows into a table, each row has a counter appended to it to create unique ID's.

each row contains a checkbox named 'treated', 'treated1','treated2' etc etc.

I want each of those checkboxes, when checked to call another function. for simplicity its just an alert.

my javascript/jquery syntax is:

```
  $('input[name^="treated"]').change(function() {
       alert('test');
    });
```

and my HTML is:

```
<td valign=top><input type="checkbox"  id="treated' + counter + '" name="treated' + counter + '" /></td>
```

where counter is a javascript incremental number

Currently thealert is not shown. is `nput[name^="treated"]` correct?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `on` delegate event for dynamically inserted elements

```
  $(document).on('change','input[name^="treated"]',function() {
   alert('test');
});
```

its better you delegate it to the closest static element present in the document (tableID) than the document itself. [link](http://jq4you.blogspot.com/2013/02/jquery-direct-and-delegate-on-event.html) to read more about on events

Comment: Thanks bipen, legendary as always! Thanks for the extra advice on the closest element.